# Virtual device setup

Tags: android

I am a first user to android programming. I am trying to set up a virtual device but it gives me the following error:

"**C:\Users\Julio\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_23_x86 emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!**"

I tried to install the Intel Haxm and the Hax kernel module; however, my computer does not allow me to download these installments. Does anyone have any suggestions to bypass this problem. Much would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to uncheck Hyper-V option from Control Panel when installing HAXM. Try [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z7xoPCv3sYs).